# How to animate certain part of UIview

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I have a view (default from UIViewController), an image view above and tool bar at top.

```
       Toolbar
      ---------
     UIImageView
     -----------
       UIView
```

This is the basic structure. I want to animate the UIView and UIImageView only not toolbar, currently when I used the code

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];

[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];

if ([directionScrolled isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
}
else if([directionScrolled isEqualToString:@"2"]){
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
}

[animation setDuration:0.20];
[animation setTimingFunction:
 [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
  kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];


[[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
```

the whole view animated,(along with toolbar). I want to exclude toolbar from animating.

Comment: Put your imageview and view in seperate view and apply animation in that view.

Comment: @aViNaSh I tried, but a white shadow is appearing between animation transitions. I want exactly same appearance as like in scrollView with paging enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange your UI structure like this

```
      UIView ( this view is assigned to UIViewController )
       |
       |------Toolbar
       |------UIView ( lets take another UIView and name it as myView)
               |-------UIImageView
```

And then execute the same code of yours.
Except,

```
 last line will be  [[self.myView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
```

Be sure that

Comment: what the problem is that a white shadow is coming when animating.